# In Python/BeautifulSoup, get_text() failed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

In Python/BeautifulSoup, below code `title` values is

```
<span class="ux-textspans"><!--F#f_7[0]-->4K Photon MONO<!--F/--></span>
```

when use `title.get_text()` to get text `4K Photon MONO`, it failed .Any can help ? Thanks!

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url='https://www.ebay.com/itm/284163810059'
req=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
title=soup.select('div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div > span > div > span')
title_text= title.get_text()
```

Comment: title or model u try to get?

Comment: `model = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'model'}).get_text(strip=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also be done using `soup.find` function.

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url='https://www.ebay.com/itm/284163810059'
req=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
title=soup.find("span", {"itemprop" : "model"})
title_text= "" if title is None else title.get_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because select, returns a list, not a single string
solve:

```py
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url='https://www.ebay.com/itm/284163810059'
req=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
title=soup.select('div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div > span > div > span')
text = ''.join(list(map(lambda t: t.get_text(),title)))
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Main issue is that you use `select` that will return a `ResultSet` and you are not able to use `get_text()` or `text` until you iterat it and call the method on each element. Another issue is your selection, it could be more specific.

###### So how to fix?

Instead of `select()` use `select_one()` to call your `get_text()` directly:

```
soup.select_one('[itemprop="model"]')
```

Be aware that you always should check that an element your try to select is available:

```
title = e.get_text() if (e:= soup.select_one('[itemprop="model"]')) else None
```

**Note:** *walrus operator requires python 3.8 or higher*

Alternative for python <3.8:

```
title = soup.select_one('[itemprop="model"]').get_text() if soup.select_one('[itemprop="model"]') else None
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url='https://www.ebay.com/itm/284163810059'
req=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text)
title = e.get_text() if (e:= soup.select_one('[itemprop="model"]')) else None
title
```

###### Output

```
4K Photon MONO
```